# how to identify in linux which driver is used by wifi usb device?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with a TL-WN722N usb wifi module from tp-link. The wifi device is working fine. 
I believe it is using the ath9k_htc driver but would like to be sure.
Is there a command to identify which driver is being used?
I've tried lsusb, modinfo, and iwconfig but can't seem to see any driver info.

Comment: lshw gives
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: f8:1a:67:1d:11:d9
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=3.5.0-36-generic firmware=1.3 ip=10.0.0.14 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

which is what I wanted.  Yay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my installation I just use:

`lsmod | grep cfg80211`

and then find the driver (iwlagn im my case) listed.